# Why Apache IoTDB deleted all time series when using "drop" command in Version 1.0.1?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I have encountered a problem in Apache IoTDB V1.0.1-standalone: when there are 3 time series in IoTDB, and I use "drop timeseries root.In.k2", then all 3 time series are gone while I only need to delete one time series.

Wonder if this is a bug or I did anything wrong, and how should this problem been solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been fixed in Version 1.1 of Apache IoTDB. You can try to update to newest version, V1.1.1, from the official website.